# Using dag_run.conf in an operator

Tags: airflow

I am passing the following as the json

```
{“name”: “john”}
```

when triggering, with this operator:

```
do_stuff = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
task_id=“do_stuff”,
spark_python_task={“python_file”: “…”,
“parameters”: f"{uid}", '\'{{ dag_run.conf["name"] if dag_run else "" }}\''},
existing_cluster_id=cluster_id
)
```

I’m getting a syntax error, but I am thinking it’s related to escaping characters… I have not used templating before.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to escape the quotes. `'{{ dag_run.conf["name"] if dag_run else "" }}'` should suffice. If you need to encode the value as json, use `'{{ (dag_run.conf["name"] if dag_run else "") | tojson }}`

Comment: ok I will give it a try

Comment: I dont know Databricks, but in a quick look to docs, the parameters should be an array of string, so you need to close with `[...,...]`. Also as already said you don't need the escaped backslash. An last Airflow use [Jinja Templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

Comment: yes an array of strings is what it expects.  I'll try '{{ (dag_run.conf["name"] if dag_run else "") | tojson }}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do_stuff = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
task_id=“do_stuff”,
spark_python_task={“python_file”: “…”,
“parameters”: [f"{uid}",'{{ (dag_run.conf["name"] if dag_run else "") | tojson }}']},
existing_cluster_id=cluster_id
)
```